# Burden of proof for birkas "she'Asa nisim"?

Tags: chanuka, halacha, blessing, see-sight-vision-blind

The law is [recorded in Shulchan Aruch](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A9%D7%95%D7%9C%D7%97%D7%9F_%D7%A2%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%9A_%D7%90%D7%95%D7%A8%D7%97_%D7%97%D7%99%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%AA%D7%A8%D7%A2%D7%95_%D7%92) *et al.* that one who sees lit *Chanuka* lights and has not lit his own should say the *b'racha* of שעשה נסים לאבותנו (*"...she'asa nisim la'avosenu..."*). Could he say this *b'racha* on a light that was lit improperly (e.g. earlier than the allowed time)? Would his due diligence require him to find out whether the flame in question came about in the proper way?

Comment: Probably Rov would be sufficient. Chanukka candles were lit near the ground so you wouldn't think they were for light and are thus easy to identify. Rov such candles are kosher, so if the market was still active you were good to go.

Comment: How could you know which entry was being lit for real and which for Chashad?

Answer (score 3):

The *Beis Hab'chira* ([*maseches Shabas 23a*](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=40769&st=&pgnum=38) - "mi she'ein lo l'hadlik" on the lower left) **quotes and approves of** the opinion that if one has no access to *Chanuka* lights of his own and cannot see others' then he should say the *b'racha* of *she'asa nisim...* anyway, implying that seeing lit lights is *a* catalyst for the *b'racha* but that it essentially applies to the occasion and is bound more or less incidentally to the lighting. This would imply that one who lacked lights could certainly recite the *b'racha* upon seeing flames of uncertain legal origin because that would be no worse than seeing no flames at all.

> מי שאין לו להדליק ואינו במקום שאפשר לו לראות יש אומרים שמברך לעצמו שעשה נסים. . . והדברים נראים

In other words, even though the *Beis Hab'chira*'s argument can't apply *directly* to the case in question since it is one in which he actually does see flames, according to him, the implicit *kal vachomer* should at least suffice to overcome the concern of *safek b'rachos* to require/allow the *b'racha* to be recited in this case.

Answer (score 2):

This Halacha only applies if you're not going to light your own Chanukiah later the same day, and you don't have someone lighting on your behalf.

You can only say the beracha on a light that is still within the required half-hour. If the light has been lit for longer than that, you cannot say the beracha. If you're unsure, you cannot say the beracha because of safek berachot l'hakel.

(Yalkut Yosef 676:7)

He doesn't specifically address your question, but I'm guessing (a) that one of the other reasons for not saying the beracha applies to you, and (b) that it's a safe extrapolation that you can't say the beracha on a candle that was lit too early. I'd guess, however, that you can generally assume the candles were lit within the proper time frame.

Comment: Can you also assume it was lit in the proper place and not moved to where it currently sits, that it was done for the mitzva, etc.?

Comment: That's what I would assume.

Comment: There's no evidence in Rishonim for such a concern, probably because you just said the blessing before the market died down and that was it. If the market was still active, then you were good to go. (They had no concept of a post-30 minute candle still lit during market hours.)