# Just one b'racha on Chanuka lights?

Tags: halacha, chanuka, blessing

There is a [possible scenario](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/4341/burden-of-proof-for-birkas-sheasa-nisim) in which one recites only the *b'racha* of *she'Asa nisim* on *neros Chanuka* without the *b'racha* of *l'hadlik ner*. Does the opposite scenario exist, in which one says only *l'hadlik ner* and not *she'Asa nisim*?

Comment: If someone said the Seeing blessing not anticipating being able to light, and then became able, seemingly he'd only follow up with the one blessing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Although he rejects the conclusion, Rav Lichtenstein entertains the possibility that a blind person would be required to say the first bracha but not the second.
http://vbm-torah.org/archive/halak66/16halak.htm

Answer (score 3):

If you are the one that lights the Chanuka candles in Shul, according to some Poskim when you light at home you only say Lhadlik Ner. (Refrences later)

Comment: Yalkut Yosef siman 671.